# Unable to fix the issue for webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is the code which contain the driver script when it's run it gives the   below issue.When it displays opening browser it throws the exception which looks like unrelated.I tried by checking  xalan.jar but it seems no problem on that side.

```
package com.totsy.test;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.totsy.xls.read.Xls_Reader;

public class DriverScript {

    public static Logger APP_LOGS;
    //suite.xlsx
    public Xls_Reader suiteXLS;
    public int currentSuiteID;
    public String currentTestSuite;

    // current test suite
    public static Xls_Reader currentTestSuiteXLS;
    public static int currentTestCaseID;
    public static String currentTestCaseName;
    public static int currentTestStepID;
    public static String currentKeyword;
    public static int currentTestDataSetID=2;
    public static Method method[];
    public static Method capturescreenShot_method;


    public static Keywords keywords;
    public static String keyword_execution_result;
    public static ArrayList<String> resultSet;
    public static String data;
    public static String object;

    // properties
    public static Properties CONFIG;
    public static Properties OR;

    public DriverScript() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
        keywords = new Keywords();
        method = keywords.getClass().getMethods();
        capturescreenShot_method =keywords.getClass().getMethod("captureScreenshot",String.class,String.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("src/test/java/com/totsy/config/config.properties");
        CONFIG= new Properties();
        CONFIG.load(fs);

        fs = new FileInputStream("src/test/java/com/totsy/config/or.properties");
        OR= new Properties();
        OR.load(fs);

        //System.out.println(CONFIG.getProperty("testsiteURL"));
        //System.out.println(OR.getProperty("name"));


        DriverScript test = new DriverScript();
        test.start();
    }


    public void start() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
        // initialize the app logs
        APP_LOGS = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
        APP_LOGS.debug("Hello");
        APP_LOGS.debug("Properties loaded. Starting testing");
        // 1) check the runmode of test Suite
        // 2) Runmode of the test case in test suite
        // 3) Execute keywords of the test case serially
        // 4) Execute Keywords as many times as
        // number of data sets - set to Y
        APP_LOGS.debug("Intialize Suite xlsx");
        suiteXLS = new Xls_Reader("src/test/java/com/totsy/xls/Suite.xlsx");


        for(currentSuiteID=2;currentSuiteID<=suiteXLS.getRowCount(Constants.TEST_SUITE_SHEET);currentSuiteID++){

            APP_LOGS.debug(suiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_SUITE_SHEET, Constants.Test_Suite_ID, currentSuiteID)+" -- "+  suiteXLS.getCellData("Test Suite", "Runmode", currentSuiteID));
            // test suite name = test suite xls file having tes cases
            currentTestSuite=suiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_SUITE_SHEET, Constants.Test_Suite_ID, currentSuiteID);
            if(suiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_SUITE_SHEET, Constants.RUNMODE, currentSuiteID).equals(Constants.RUNMODE_YES)){
                // execute the test cases in the suite
                APP_LOGS.debug("******Executing the Suite******"+suiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_SUITE_SHEET, Constants.Test_Suite_ID, currentSuiteID));
                currentTestSuiteXLS=new Xls_Reader("src/test/java/com/totsy/xls/"+currentTestSuite+".xlsx");
                // iterate through all the test cases in the suite
                for(currentTestCaseID=2;currentTestCaseID<=currentTestSuiteXLS.getRowCount("Test Cases");currentTestCaseID++){
                    APP_LOGS.debug(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_CASES_SHEET, Constants.TCID, currentTestCaseID)+" -- "+currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData("Test Cases", "Runmode", currentTestCaseID));
                    currentTestCaseName=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_CASES_SHEET, Constants.TCID, currentTestCaseID);

                    if(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_CASES_SHEET, Constants.RUNMODE, currentTestCaseID).equals(Constants.RUNMODE_YES)){
                        APP_LOGS.debug("Executing the test case -> "+currentTestCaseName);
                        if(currentTestSuiteXLS.isSheetExist(currentTestCaseName)){
                            // RUN as many times as number of test data sets with runmode Y
                            for(currentTestDataSetID=2;currentTestDataSetID<=currentTestSuiteXLS.getRowCount(currentTestCaseName);currentTestDataSetID++)
                            {
                                resultSet = new ArrayList<String>();
                                APP_LOGS.debug("Iteration number "+(currentTestDataSetID-1));
                                // checking the runmode for the current data set
                                if(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, Constants.RUNMODE, currentTestDataSetID).equals(Constants.RUNMODE_YES)){

                                    // iterating through all keywords
                                    executeKeywords(); // multiple sets of data
                                }
                                createXLSReport();
                            }
                        }else{
                            // iterating through all keywords
                            resultSet= new ArrayList<String>();
                            executeKeywords();// no data with the test
                            createXLSReport();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


    public void executeKeywords() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        // iterating through all keywords
        for(currentTestStepID=2;currentTestStepID<=currentTestSuiteXLS.getRowCount(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET);currentTestStepID++){
            // checking TCID
            if(currentTestCaseName.equals(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, Constants.TCID, currentTestStepID))){

                data=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, Constants.DATA,currentTestStepID  );
                if(data.startsWith(Constants.DATA_START_COL)){
                    // read actual data value from the corresponding column
                    data=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, data.split(Constants.DATA_SPLIT)[1] ,currentTestDataSetID );
                }else if(data.startsWith(Constants.CONFIG)){
                    //read actual data value from config.properties
                    data=CONFIG.getProperty(data.split(Constants.DATA_SPLIT)[1]);
                }else{
                    //by default read actual data value from or.properties
                    data=OR.getProperty(data);
                }
                object=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, Constants.OBJECT,currentTestStepID  );
                currentKeyword=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, Constants.KEYWORD, currentTestStepID);
                APP_LOGS.debug(currentKeyword);
                // code to execute the keywords as well
                // reflection API

                for(int i=0;i<method.length;i++){

                    if(method[i].getName().equals(currentKeyword)){
                        keyword_execution_result=(String)method[i].invoke(keywords,object,data);
                        APP_LOGS.debug(keyword_execution_result);
                        resultSet.add(keyword_execution_result);
                        // capture screenshot
                        capturescreenShot_method.invoke(keywords,
                                currentTestSuite+"_"+currentTestCaseName+"_TS"+currentTestStepID+"_"+(currentTestDataSetID-1),
                                keyword_execution_result);

                        //how do we call
                        // what will be the file name




                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void createXLSReport(){

        String colName=Constants.RESULT +(currentTestDataSetID-1);
        boolean isColExist=false;

        for(int c=0;c<currentTestSuiteXLS.getColumnCount(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET);c++){
            if(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET,c , 1).equals(colName)){
                isColExist=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!isColExist)
            currentTestSuiteXLS.addColumn(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, colName);
        int index=0;
        for(int i=2;i<=currentTestSuiteXLS.getRowCount(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET);i++){

            if(currentTestCaseName.equals(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, Constants.TCID, i))){
                if(resultSet.size()==0)
                    currentTestSuiteXLS.setCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, colName, i, Constants.KEYWORD_SKIP);
                else
                    currentTestSuiteXLS.setCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, colName, i, resultSet.get(index));
                index++;
            }


        }

        if(resultSet.size()==0){
            // skip
            currentTestSuiteXLS.setCellData(currentTestCaseName, Constants.RESULT, currentTestDataSetID, Constants.KEYWORD_SKIP);
            return;
        }else{
            for(int i=0;i<resultSet.size();i++){
                if(!resultSet.get(i).equals(Constants.KEYWORD_PASS)){
                    currentTestSuiteXLS.setCellData(currentTestCaseName, Constants.RESULT, currentTestDataSetID, resultSet.get(i));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        currentTestSuiteXLS.setCellData(currentTestCaseName, Constants.RESULT, currentTestDataSetID, Constants.KEYWORD_PASS);
        //  if(!currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, "Runmode",currentTestDataSetID).equals("Y")){}

    }






}
```

Below is the issue which is unable to understand.What would be the workaround for this as it after displaying the open browser it throws the exception.I suspected that I suspect that it would be because of older jdk but after updating also it is showing the same issue.

```
2016-03-01 20:39:37 DEBUG devpinoyLogger:70 - Hello
2016-03-01 20:39:37 DEBUG devpinoyLogger:71 - Properties loaded. Starting testing
2016-03-01 20:39:37 DEBUG devpinoyLogger:77 - Intialize Suite xlsx
2016-03-01 20:39:39 DEBUG devpinoyLogger:83 - Check out -- Y
2016-03-01 20:39:39 DEBUG devpinoyLogger:88 - ******Executing the Suite******Check out
2016-03-01 20:39:40 DEBUG devpinoyLogger:92 - ShoppingCart -- Y
2016-03-01 20:39:40 DEBUG devpinoyLogger:96 - Executing the test case -> ShoppingCart
2016-03-01 20:39:40 DEBUG devpinoyLogger:102 - Iteration number 1
2016-03-01 20:39:40 DEBUG devpinoyLogger:144 - openBrowser
2016-03-01 20:39:40 DEBUG devpinoyLogger:40 - Opening browser
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.totsy.test.DriverScript.executeKeywords(DriverScript.java:151)
    at com.totsy.test.DriverScript.start(DriverScript.java:107)
    at com.totsy.test.DriverScript.main(DriverScript.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.saxon.Configuration.newConfiguration()Lnet/sf/saxon/Configuration;
    at net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl.<init>(XPathFactoryImpl.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryFinder.loadFromService(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryFinder._newFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryFinder.newFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.readIdFromInstallRdf(FileExtension.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.writeTo(FileExtension.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ClasspathExtension.writeTo(ClasspathExtension.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.installExtensions(FirefoxProfile.java:425)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk(FirefoxProfile.java:403)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at com.totsy.test.Keywords.openBrowser(Keywords.java:42)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for making it better.

Comment: Check the exact version of the library which contains `net.sf.saxon.Configuration` and whether the class in that version provides method `newConfiguration()`. If you have a version on your classpath that doesn't provide that method that would result in such an error. Note that you could have multiple libs containing that class on your classpath which would then depend on the order the classloader loads the classes in (and which you don't want to change manually) - so look for multiple versions of the same lib or different libs with the same class as well.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20110486/954442